# Configuring Health Indicators for Spring Cloud Config Server (4.0.2)

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

I'm trying to understand how to enable the default health indicators in my config server.

The version of Spring Cloud is 4.0.2.

The version of Spring Boot is 3.1.2.

The config server responds appropriately when calling */config-client/development*, which is good and everything works as expected with the client and the Vault.

Back to the health indications: my understanding is that I don't need to add the actuator starter, so I didn't. (by the way: including it doesn't make a difference anyway)

I edited the application.yml of the config server as read in the documentation:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        health:
          repositories:
            myservice-dev:
              name: config-client
              profiles: development
```

And I think that this is correct, but maybe it's not...?

When I send a GET request to */actuator/health*, I expect status "UP", but I get:

```
{
    "name": "actuator",
    "profiles": [
        "health"
    ],
    "label": null,
    "version": null,
    "state": null,
    "propertySources": []
}
```

This is very confusing. I hope that someone can clarify what's happening.

Comment: You do have to add the actuator. When you request `/actuator/health` you are getting a config server response. We recommend running actuator on a different port.

Comment: As I wrote, I tried to add actuator as dependency without success. I'll try to change the port (again) and keep you posted. I'll do this in an empty project, so that I can share it later, eventually